# How can I inherit from a class that can't be instanciated with certain template parameters because of a function that I'm overriding?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, instantiation, virtual-functions

I have some code similar to the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class A
{
    virtual void failifint()
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_same<T, int>(), "T is an int!");
    }
};

class B : public A <int>
{
    virtual void failifint()
    {
        // Don't fail
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b ;
}
```

I'd expect any code that contains an an `A<T>` object to compile whenever `T` isn't an `int`, and code that has a `B` to compile since `failifint()` is overriden to an int-compilable version. However, the aforementioned code fails because of the static assertion even though there isn't any `A<int>` instanciated.

Why does this happen? And how can I create `B` with a special implementation of `failifint` that doesn't fail in a compilation error because of its implementation in `A`?

Comment: What do you mean _"However, the aforementioned code fails because of the static assertion even though there isn't any A<int> instanciated."_ It certainly is: `class B : public A <int>`.

Comment: You should not mix static (template) and dynamic (virtual) polymorphism, unless you have a good reason.

Comment: @awesomeyi For me personally: as already noted in the comments, the question states that `A<int>` is never instantiated even though the reference to `A<int>` is right there in the OP's own code, in a form that clearly requires instantiation. I have tried, but I'm unable to even guess what the OP could have been thinking while typing up this question. That part just makes no sense to me, even if I look at it again a few times. I must admit that for a question that I am unable to make sense of, it's nonetheless one of the better written ones though. :)

Comment: Maybe the example I wrote was a little bit too generic and "obvious". Anyway, I didn't consider that `A<int>::failifint` **needed** to be instantiated since it could be called from A's destructor, like Dani's answer.
A more obvious reason why this fails is that I can call `using A::failifint()` somewhere on `B` to use that version of the virtual function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have a problem with your attempt:

```
class A
{
    virtual void print() { cout << "A" << endl; }
    virtual ~A() { print(); }
}

class B : A
{
    virtual void print() { cout << "B" << endl; }
}

...

B b;
```

Will print A on destruct, not B. So there is an `A` being instantiated when you instantiate a `B`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `static_assert` is a *compile time* feature, it check the condition during compilation, while virtual functions call/dispatch is handled at run-time. The compiler still have to compile the function in the base class, which will cause the assertion.

Comment: But how can I make something similar to this? My original code code has this problem because the equivalent of `A` has two template parameters and its `failifint` tries to `static_cast` between them, which fails if the two types aren't compatible as it's the case with the class where `B` inherits. This shouldn't be a problem since my `failifint` is overloaded.

Comment: (A) Overloading is usually taken to refer to operators or function signatures, not polymorphic member functions; the word in the latter context is _override_. (B) Your mfunc is not overridden, because it is neither `virtual` (which would be a bad idea in almost any static polymorphism context), nor statically polymorphic by the base call wrapping a `static_casted` `this`->function in the derived type. The latter would require the CRTP, which would take us in quite a different direction. Really, just use a better approach. Derived classes should generally remove restrictions, not add them.

Answer (score 0):

"However, the aforementioned code fails because of the static assertion even though there isn't any A instanciated."

But there is one: through B. B is an A.

"And how can I create B with a special implementation of failifint that doesn't fail in a compilation error because of its implementation in A?"

You can't as long as A's failifint is virtual. What you could do instead is override it. Just remove the virtual keyword. This will hide A's failifint.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        void failifint()
        {
            static_assert(!std::is_same<T, int>(), "T is an int!");
            printf("A failifint\n");
        }
};

class B : public A <int>
{
    public:
        void failifint()
        {
            printf("B\n");
        }
};
```

And if in main you have the following code, a.failifint will give compile time error.

`B b;
 A<int> a;
b.failifint(); // B
a.failifint(); //compile error`

If, however, you **must** have A's failifint's functionality be extended via virtual methods, you could do something like this as well

```
// Abstract base
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void failifint() = 0;
};

// Can be of type int
class B : public A <int>
{
    public:
        void failifint()
        {
            printf("B\n");
        }
};

// Anything deriving from C cannot be int
class C : public A <typename T>
{
    public:
        virtual void failifint()
        {
            static_assert(!std::is_same<T, int>(), "T is an int!");
            printf("C failifint\n");
        }
};
```

This will allow some A's to throw exceptions on int's, and some not. If they derive directly from A, then you're good. If they derive from C, they cannot be of type int.

Comment: It will not "replace" A's `failifint`. It will _hide_ it. The difference is very important.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I knew there was a word I was forgetting.